# How to link PHP 5.3 (FastCGI) to cURL with Lighttpd on Mac OS X?

Tags: php, macos, curl, lighttpd

I installed `lighttpd`, `php5 +fastcgi`, and `php5-curl` earlier this morning using MacPorts. I have been able to get the former two working fine, but I can't seem to get PHP to see the installed cURL extension. I did not change the install path for cURL - it is now at `/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/curl.so`.

I've added a line into my PHP file as well:

```
extension=curl.so
```

I've tried this line as well as one using the absolute path, restarting the server in between tries, but nothing has made cURL show up as an extension when I run a test page with `phpinfo()`.

Am I missing a step here? Do I need to reconfigure and recompile PHP with an option for cURL, maybe?

Comment: Bump. I'm having the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you view the error message of Lighttpd? I guess there might be a problem with loading the curl.so, and it will be there.